# strtotime confusing..?

Tags: php, date

How come

```
$a = "Thursday, 10 January, 2013";
```

gives me **2012-01-12** when I do

```
$b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects the string to be an English-formatted date.  As the above is obviously not so, it is not going to return expected results.  As an example, the following will render correctly:

```
$a = "January 10, 2013";
$b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a));
echo $b;
```